# editText background set but does not show up when application is launched

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, user-interface, android-edittext

I have created a login page which has two editText fields for username and password. I have included an ImageView in the activity also.
I have made an XML file to make rounded white background for the editText fields. However, that did not work and was still transparent. On changing the background from the created XML file to simple white colour, I could still not see the editText fields.

Below is the code I have used for the following:

### Login.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:onClick="Clicked"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="307dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="327dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
        android:foreground="@drawable/emailsignup"
        android:text="@string/button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.104"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="293dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="146dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="63dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:foreground="@drawable/gmailsignup"
        android:text="@string/button2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.006"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="269dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="253dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:background="@drawable/loginbg"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="@string/LoginText"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
         android:layout_width="228dp"
         android:layout_height="51dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="95dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="179dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
         android:autofillHints=""
         android:background="@drawable/edittextround"
         android:ems="10"
         android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
         android:hint="@string/PasswordHint"
         android:inputType="textPassword"
         android:textSize="24sp"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.978"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
         android:layout_width="281dp"
         android:layout_height="54dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="320dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="153dp"
         android:layout_marginStart="58dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
         android:autofillHints=""
         android:ems="10"
         android:background="@drawable/edittextround"
         android:hint="@string/LoginTextHint"
         android:inputType="textPersonName"
         android:textSize="24sp"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
         app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.962" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView"
         android:layout_width="566dp"
         android:layout_height="972dp"
         android:adjustViewBounds="false"
         android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
         android:cropToPadding="false"
         android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.344"
         app:srcCompat="@drawable/picture1_2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### edittextround.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
     <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
     <gradient
         android:centerY="0.2"
         android:startColor="#D3D3D3"
         android:centerColor="#65FFFFFF"
         android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
         android:angle="270"
         />
     <stroke
         android:width="0.7dp"
         android:color="#BDBDBD" />
     <corners
         android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

I tried putting the edittextbackground.xml on the login button and it worked perfectly.

The images related to this activity are below:

[Image of the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7y4Z.png)

Please help me figure out why my editText fields do not show their backgrounds

Comment: what happens if you don't set any background?

Comment: I tried your code and it seems to work just fine, maybe its just now rendering on ur preview tab.Did you try to run it on a device

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I tried removing the editText background and nothing changed while removing the ImageView itself works but I wish to put the image as well

Comment: @Ibrahim117 I did try to run on my phone, and I couldn't see the editText fields

Comment: @MirandaJones you should definitely checkout Abhinav  's answer he's got a legit point . Your ImageView is rendering on top of the editText and the thing with constraint layout is it will keep the last element on top and as in your case the last element is image view with static height and width and therefore covers almost the whole screen, try to put your imageview on the very top just below the constraintLayout, and if you are using it just as the background simply use the background attribute in the constraint layout and you won't have to define a separate element for this.

Comment: @Ibrahim117 Thank you so much. I understood.

Comment: @MirandaJones no sweat stay safe and have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok got it

so the problem is below

`app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"`
`app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"`

you are setting the constraints to imageView and that imageView also renders in the area of Editext but not in the background because it is at same elevation as of Editexts so if you just increase the elevation of of editexts they will show up , i tried it , it works 
just add `android:elevation="1dp"` in both edittexts the imageview is at 0dp so editext will show above it.

Although it works but your constraints are confusing use `parent` instead

`app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` 
`app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`
`app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button"` will also do

also i want to say if you use constraint layout correctly you will not need to set `layout_width` and `layout_height` in most cases you can set them to 0 the constraints will determine the correct width and height also you don't need to use margins your constraint will handle them if you use bias, chains, groups ,barrier, guidelines etc correctly  , please learn more about constraint layout and you can reduce the lines in above layout file to half.

[this](https://youtu.be/Ske1_LuymRI) tutorial will give you good start, also watch other videos in that series

**have a good day**

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood your explanation and I will try to make the constraints less confusing by taking help from the link you provided. Have a great day and hope you stay safe.